# Why is Entity Framework building non-SARgable predicates

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework 6.1.1 with code first and DbContext.

Take this a simple query:

```
Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyID == "aPRoperty")
```

The generated and executed SQL query is:

```
WHERE N'aPRoperty' = [Extent1].[PropertyID]
```

However, propertyID in the database is varchar(10). So the above predicate does an Index Scan rather than Index Seek. This is due to the different datatypes in the predicate.

I can force the correct query by using:

```
Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyID == DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode("aPRoperty"))
```

This generates the parameter without the N unicode specifier and we get an Index Seek.

1. Is this a bug? The fields is mapped IsUnicode(false) in the code first mapping.
2. Is there a global way to configure this without having to use the Dbfunction in every query we do against a char or varchar field in the database?

Comment: When I map a property as IsUnicode(false) I don't see a unicode search string in the query.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, another dev here saw it working correctly. I rebuilt my model dll and reload linqpad and it appears to be correct now. I'm not sure what the heck was going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can globally map all strings to varchar in the OnModelCreating event.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.IsUnicode(false));  
}
```

Comment: Well, most databases that have this issue are mixed.

Comment: The property *is* mapped as `IsUnicode(false)`. And it's not said that all string properties should be non-unicode.

Comment: Thanks @neil that's good to know, but not exactly what I was asking about. Seems I am going bonkers it is Friday the 13th close to quitting time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the false alarm all. It seems like it is working correctly after I rebuilt my model dll and reloaded it into linqpad.

My apologies to the EF team for cursing your name for a few minutes there.